# Record with union type in typescript it's not working

Tags: typescript

What I'm doing wrong?

I need type that accept an object with properties and functions callback.. like this one

```
type EventCallback = () => void
type EventsType =
    | 'beforeshow'
    | 'show'
    | 'shown'
    | 'beforehide'
    | 'hidden'
    | 'hide';

type UIkitModalEvents = Record<EventsType, EventCallback>;

const event2: UIkitModalEvents = { /// ERROR ON event2 variable
    hidden: () => {
        console.log('s');
    },
};
console.log(event2);
```

> Type '{ hidden: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<EventsType, EventCallback>': beforeshow, show, shown, beforehide, hide(2739)

You can check [on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAwgQwDYYEZoMYDWUAvFABQCUJAfFHAPYCWAJgFCiSwLIDOAKuGjFWUUVAA+UAOTYIAM3oAnCDwAW9AO5SRYyVLWbtYidIMbER3dNkLlqlhEui995syROTU144DcrdkEoAFUASQJGYABZemZMeCRgHhIoACUIPCVmAB4E3gFIABouRPQsXEJqf1ZMxB5gKAhuYAAmAC4Q8MiYuIw8pJSAbx1RV3dEDsoaKGHjY1qeegwIADoMegBzMn0pCn9jAF9C1gP-BaXV9a2mxJa9oA)

Comment: Does Partial do the trick for you? `const event2: Partial<UIkitModalEvents>` (This way event2 can contain any set of callbacks for defined events)

Comment: @Lesiak Partial works for me… if you want you can add an answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code you need to provide a callback for each event type. To make your code more flexible and accept an object with any subset of event types, you can use Partial

```
const event2: Partial<UIkitModalEvents>
```